# How to use nested groupBy in angular fillter

Tags: angularjs

I want to develop a dynamic menu system using JSON object for that I'm using angular-fillter.js ,but I'm unable to get the correct output.

I'm expecting out put like this:

1.Topic 
    page_Name
     - Category
        cate1
           description
        cate2
           descrption
              - SubCategory
                sub1
                  description
                sub2
                   description

my app.js:

```js
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) { 

$scope.items =
      [{"$id":"1",
"userid":1,
"topic":"topic",
"topicOrderId":1,
"category":"cate1",
"catOrderId":1,
"subCategory":"sub1",
"subCatOrderId":1,
"page_Name":"page_Name1",
"pageId":1,
"url":"dashboard/index",
"description":"description1",
"tooltip":"topic1"},
{"$id":"2",
"userid":1,
"topic":"topic",
"topicOrderId":1,
"category":"cate1",
"catOrderId":1,
"subCategory":"sub2",
"subCatOrderId":1,
"page_Name":"page_Name2",
"pageId":1,
"url":"dashboard/index2",
"description":"description2",
"tooltip":"topic2"},


{"$id":"3",
"userid":1,
"topic":"topic",
"topicOrderId":1,
"category":"cate2",
"catOrderId":1,
"subCategory":"sub4",
"subCatOrderId":1,
"page_Name":"page_Name3",
"pageId":1,
"url":"dashboard/index3",
"description":"description3",
"tooltip":"topic4"},

{"$id":"4",
"userid":1,
"topic":"topic",
"topicOrderId":1,
"category":"cate3",
"catOrderId":1,
"subCategory":"sub3",
"subCatOrderId":1,
"page_Name":"page_Name4",
"pageId":1,
"url":"dashboard/index4",
"description":"description4",
"tooltip":"topic4"},

{"$id":"5",
"userid":1,
"topic":"topic",
"topicOrderId":1,
"category":"cate2",
"catOrderId":1,
"subCategory":"sub5",
"subCatOrderId":1,
"page_Name":"page_Name5",
"pageId":1,
"url":"dashboard2/index",
"description":"description5",
"tooltip":"topic5"}];
});
```

and my html file:

```xml
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
        <div  ng-repeat="(key, value) in items | groupBy: 'topic'" >
            <label> {{key}} </label>  
            <li> {{value.pageName}} </li>               
            <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                <div ng-repeat=" (key , val) in value | groupBy: 'category' ">  
                    <label>{{key}}</label>
                    <li>
                    {{val.description}}
                    </li>           
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none" >
                        <div ng-repeat="x in val"> 
                            <li>{{x.subCategory}} </li>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Here I want to group by topic and group category as well, the logic works fine but I'm unable to print value of page_Name, Description 
please let me know how to do this

[image]